# Как отфильтровать объекты в массиве по значениям?

Tags: php

Есть массив объектов у которых есть параметры: pay и cart, которые имеют значение 1 или 0. Я принимаю GET параметры pay и cart со значениями:

```
if(isset($_GET['pay'])) {
    $pay_get = $_GET['pay'];
} else {
    $pay_get = false;
}

if(isset($_GET['cart'])) {
    $cart_get = $_GET['cart'];
} else {
    $cart_get = false;
}
```

И пытаюсь отфильтровать массив по этим значениям:

```
foreach ($arr => $item) {

    //Фильтр по выкупу
        if($pay_get != false && $pay_get != $item->pay) {
            continue;
        }
        //Фильтр по карте
        if($cart_get != false && $cart_get != $item->cart) {
            continue;
        }

        $object = new stdClass;
        $object->name = $item->name;
        $object->properties->pay = $item->pay;
        $object->properties->cart = $item->cart;

        array_push($new_filtered_array, $object);
    }
```

Но что то не выходит корректно отфильтровать, мозги что то уже отказываются понимать почему. Как тут быть?

Comment: А зачем вам третье состояние? 1, 0, false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$GET = [
    'pay' => 0,
    'card' => 1,
    'test' => false,
];

$arr = [
    0 => (object)['pay' => 1],
    1 => (object)['card' => 1],
    2 => (object)['pay' => 0],
    3 => (object)['card' => 0],
    4 => (object)['card' => 0, 'pay' => 1],
    5 => (object)['card' => 1, 'pay' => 1],
    6 => (object)['card' => 0, 'pay' => 0],
    7 => (object)['card' => 1, 'pay' => 0],
];

$allowedFilter = [
    'pay',
    'card',
];
$allowedValues = [0, 1];

foreach ($arr as $index => $item) {
    $allFilter = true;

    foreach ($allowedFilter as $key) {
        if (!isset($GET[$key]) || !in_array($GET[$key], $allowedValues)) {
            //Нет фильтра, либо значение неправильно. Игнорируем фильтр
            continue;
        }

        if (empty($GET[$key]) && empty($item->$key)) {
            //Фильтр неактивный, значение тоже должно быть неактивно, для принятия
        } elseif (!empty($GET[$key]) && !empty($item->$key)) {
            //Фильтр активный, значение тоже должно быть активно, для принятия
        } else {
            //Фильтр отличается от значения, охрана отмена =)
            $allFilter &= false;
        }
    }

    if ($allFilter) {
        echo "Все фильтры совпали в позиции #{$index}\n";
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/Q5fi1L

Comment: Только не забывайте также что в ```$_GET``` может прийти что угодно, ну и не ясно безопасны ли данные в ```$arr```